# Cannot import android.arch.persistence.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have read [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration). I also clone [android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) then I try to add Mirgration test. However, I cannot import

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper;
```

I also use latest lib version which is.

```
android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0-alpha3
```

Here is the code for MigrationTest

```
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.arch.persistence.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MigrationTest {
    private static final String TEST_DB = "migration-test";

    @Rule
    public MigrationTestHelper helper;

    public MigrationTest() {
        helper = new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
                MigrationDb.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
    }

    @Test
    public void migrate1To2() throws IOException {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 1);

        // db has schema version 1. insert some data using SQL queries.
        // You cannot use DAO classes because they expect the latest schema.
        //db.execSQL(...);

        // Prepare for the next version.
        db.close();

        // Re-open the database with version 2 and provide
        // MIGRATION_1_2 as the migration process.
        db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, MIGRATION_1_2);

        // MigrationTestHelper automatically verifies the schema changes,
        // but you need to validate that the data was migrated properly.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the code use AndroidJUnit4 then Just use androidTestCompile instead

```
 androidTestCompile "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$arch_version"
```

Official doc use dependency for local unit test. However, the official sample use Android runner...

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Answer (score 7):

You are using Android runner (`AndroidJUnit4.class`), and your test is actualy placed at `src/androidTest`. It means you are using `Instrumented Tests` which dependencies should be declared:

```
// Instrumented Unit Test or UI Test
androidTestComplile ....
```

Meanwhile, if you are writing `Local Unit Test`, testing codes is placed at `src/test`, you can declare the dependencies:

```
// Local Unit Test
testCompile ....
```

In Google documentation, they just give an example for local unit tests. No mistake here.

Comment: Thank you. Can we run that code as a local unit test on host machine?

Comment: I think there is a mistake since their sample code use AndroidJUnit4

Comment: They are using `AndroidJUnit4` under folder `src/androidTest` which requires emulator or real devices to run on.

Comment: Under folder `src/test`, they are using `JUnit` which runs on local Java Virtual Machine(JVM), so you do not need to connect to emulator or real devices.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue is google provide documentation for JUnit **local** tests cases and not instrumental (which means tests on a real device or emulator).

As a result i saw many example with

```
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

This makes not sense cause you can only test your room db with instrumental test cases. You will get an error otherwise. So you have to use **androidTestImplementation** and not testImplementation in your gradle file.

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
def test_version = "1.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$test_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$test_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers of [Quang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799109/2660216) and [UmAnusorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753178/2660216) are correct but a little outdated. For those who like to know:

- Use `androidTestImplementation` instead of `androidTestCompile`
- AndroidX: `androidx.room:room-testing`

Complete implementation in gradle:

`androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"`

(2.2.4 is the latest version at the moment of writing)

Comment: 2.5.0 at the moment of reading.